# Building a dataframe based on two other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df=
name   group  feedback     question
a      g1     False        abc
a      g1     True         abc
a      g1     True         xyz
b      g1     True         xyz
b      g1     True         abc
c      g1     False        def
d      g2     False        xyz
d      g2     True         xyz
e      g2     True         xyz
f      g3     True         abc
f      g3     True         www
g      g3     False        xyz
h      g4     True         www
h      g4     True         qqq
i      g4     False        xyz
```

I also have a dataframe that contains pairs of these groups (and some other columns that are unimportant). It usually, but **NOT** always contains all the possible pairs.

```
df_2=
Group1   Group2    Value
g1       g2        0.25
g1       g3        0.50
g2       g3        0.25
g3       g4        0.50
```

I want to build a new dataframe that has the following header:

```
Group1   Group2   question    ScoreGroup1    ScoreGroup2
```

The `question` will be the common questions each pair has answered. The `ScoreGroup1` is the number of `Trues/(Trues+Falses)` answers for that question for `Group1`, analogously for `Group2`. So in the case above:

```
Group1   Group2   question      ScoreGroup1         ScoreGroup2
g1       g2       xyz                     1                0.66
g1       g3       abc                  0.66                   1
g1       g3       xyz                     1                   0
g2       g3       xyz                  0.66                   0
g3       g4       www                     1                   1
g3       g4       xyz                     0                   0
```

What I did so far: grouping by group in the original dataframe and `feeback.mean()`, but that only gives me an overall ranking of the groups. I need to make use of the pairing and the questions that are common. I found which questions are common by doing:

```
mutuals = df.groupby('group')['question'].apply(set)
```

But how do I compute these pairwise scores?

EDIT: These are the dataframes:

```
df = {'name':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i'],
        'group':['g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g3', 'g3', 'g3', 'g4', 'g4', 'g4'],
        'feedback': [False, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False],
         'question': ['abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'abc', 'www', 'xyz', 'www', 'qqq', 'xyz]}

df_2 = {'Group1': ['g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3'],
        'Group2': ['g2', 'g3', 'g3', 'g4'],
        'Value': [0.25, 0.50, 0.25, 0.50]}
```

Comment: could U post pd.DataFrame() - for creating that dataset and playing with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by same `DataFrame` with remove rows if same values first, then aggregate mean:

```
df = (df.merge(df, on='question', suffixes=('1','2'))
        .query('group1 != group2')
        .groupby(['group1','group2','question'], as_index=False)
        .mean())
print (df)
   group1 group2 question  feedback1  feedback2
0      g1     g2      xyz   1.000000   0.666667
1      g1     g3      abc   0.666667   1.000000
2      g1     g3      xyz   1.000000   0.000000
3      g1     g4      xyz   1.000000   0.000000
4      g2     g1      xyz   0.666667   1.000000
5      g2     g3      xyz   0.666667   0.000000
6      g2     g4      xyz   0.666667   0.000000
7      g3     g1      abc   1.000000   0.666667
8      g3     g1      xyz   0.000000   1.000000
9      g3     g2      xyz   0.000000   0.666667
10     g3     g4      www   1.000000   1.000000
11     g3     g4      xyz   0.000000   0.000000
12     g4     g1      xyz   0.000000   1.000000
13     g4     g2      xyz   0.000000   0.666667
14     g4     g3      www   1.000000   1.000000
15     g4     g3      xyz   0.000000   0.000000
```

And last create same columns names for inner join by `df_2`:

```
d = {'Group1':'group1','Group2':'group2'}
df = df.merge(df_2[['Group1','Group2']].rename(columns=d))
print (df)
  group1 group2 question  feedback1  feedback2
0     g1     g2      xyz   1.000000   0.666667
1     g1     g3      abc   0.666667   1.000000
2     g1     g3      xyz   1.000000   0.000000
3     g2     g3      xyz   0.666667   0.000000
4     g3     g4      www   1.000000   1.000000
5     g3     g4      xyz   0.000000   0.000000
```